# How to align absolute positioned element to parent's parent

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario of navigation:

The navigation bar is red and on it is one navigation `li`. The blue area is a drop down menu for the navigation button. The drop down menu is positioned absolutely and therefore is aligned at the left edge of the `li` element. What I want is for the drop down to be positioned absolutely but to be aligned at the left edge of the navigation bar (red container).

I already tried `left: 0` and for some reason it isn't working in my scenario. Are there any alternatives to get it to align to the `.navigation-bar`?

What it looks like now
[image]

What it needs to look like
[image]

Comment: `ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply margin: 0 and padding: 0 to the ul.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the padding and margin on the `li` that's moving it across.

Try adding this to your css on your `.navigation-bar ul li` selector:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

Final output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navigation-bar {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .navigation-bar ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .align-me {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 1080px;
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigation-bar">
    <li>Navigation button</li>
    <div class="align-me">I need to be aligned to .navigation-bar</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pedram said in comments, you need to reset `margin` and `padding` properties. You can write `ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`, but the good practice (and I always use it), is to reset `margin` and `padding` of ALL elements using `*` selector. It will be much easier to write your markup:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
   body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
   }
   .navigation-bar {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
   }
   .navigation-bar ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
   }
   .align-me {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 1080px;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class="navigation-bar">
   <ul>
    <li>Navigation button</li>
    <div class="align-me">I need to be aligned to .navigation-bar</div>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @opportunityr, you can use `.navigation-bar` selector, or better use `*`.